# Can I save money when flying twice to the same destination?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, budget

I heard that it was possible to purchase another plane ticket very cheaply if you were flying to the same destination within a certain period of time. Is it true? How do you do this?

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Answer (score 38):

There used to be some tricks in this area if the airline sells significantly cheaper return tickets if the stay included a weekend. Some airlines did this on the assumption that the more price-sensitive leisure travel was more likely to include weekend stays than the less price-sensitive business travel.

Suppose you live in city A and need to be in city B on Tuesday and Wednesday of each of two consecutive weeks. The natural choice is two A to B return tickets, each outbound on Monday and inbound on Thursday of the same week. Neither includes a weekend:

```
Ticket 1 Outbound
Ticket 1 Inbound
Weekend
Ticket 2 Outbound
Ticket 2 Inbound
```

Now consider making Ticket 1 an A to B return, outbound on Monday of week 1, inbound on Thursday of week 2. Ticket 2 is a B to A return, outbound on Thursday of week 1, inbound on Monday of week 2. Each ticket has a weekend between the outbound and inbound flights:

```
Ticket 1 Outbound
Ticket 2 Outbound
Weekend
Ticket 2 Inbound
Ticket 1 Inbound
```

I think giving preference to weekend stays has become less common, so this is an obsolete technique.

Comment: I do this with KLM and is still possible.

Comment: This would be an even better answer if you researched a particular itinerary and gave information on the price difference.

Comment: It's a pretty generic answer befitting a pretty generic question, IMHO.

Comment: I believe this strategy is known as *[back-to-back ticketing](/questions/36814/)* (or *nested ticketing*), which the airlines have [long frowned upon](http://articles.latimes.com/1994-04-21/business/fi-48686_1_business-travel) as it circumvents minimum stay requirements. So long as Ticket 1 and Ticket 2 are on different, non-partner airlines, however, it's non-enforceable in practice, though people do get [caught in the middle](http://mashable.com/2014/12/30/hidden-city-ticketing/).

Comment: I've also seen internationally where A<->B (round-trip originating at A) and B<->A (round-trip originating at B) are quite different price due to the flights being priced in the originating country's market, even though they are exactly the same airplane and perhaps even the exact same seats. YMMV but you may be able to use this to your advantage as well.